# jQuery code doesn't work in internet explorer 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have the following page http://valogiannis.com/freelancer/ecommerce-final/

In the right there are three images and in the left a big one. When the user click any of the three images in the right then the big image must change to the appropriate. I set the big images from css as background images and the small via html.

In all browsers I tested in windows platform (firefox,opera,safari,chrome,ie8) works fine but in internet explorer 7 it doesn't work. It doesn't the image image to the appropriate and also doesn't add the border in the current small image.

My jQuery code is the following:

```
$("#smallImage img").click(function() { 
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");

    var index = $(this).attr('class');
    if (index == "First current") {$("#bigImage").removeClass().addClass("bigImageFirst"); }
    else if (index == "Second current") {$("#bigImage").removeClass().addClass("bigImageSecond");  }
    else if (index == "Third current") {$("#bigImage").removeClass().addClass("bigImageThird"); }
});
```

**EDIT:** I created a live example to be able to edit whatever you think can solve the problem http://jsbin.com/ehota4/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update for updated question:* The issue is repeated ID usage, `smallImage` should be a class instead here, then use `$(".smallImage img")` as your selector.

[You can test an updated/working version here](http://jsbin.com/ehota4/4).

---

*Previous answer:*
Try using the built-in methods for this (since `class` strings may vary by spacing, but still match), like this:

```
$("#smallImage img").click(function() { 
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    var $this = $(this).addClass("current");  
    if ($this.hasClass("First")) { $("#bigImage").removeClass().addClass("bigImageFirst"); }
    else if ($this.hasClass("Second")) { $("#bigImage").removeClass().addClass("bigImageSecond");  }
    else if ($this.hasClass("Third")) { $("#bigImage").removeClass().addClass("bigImageThird"); }
});
```

Or if the class names are that certain, use it to your advantage:

```
$("#smallImage img").click(function() {
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    var c = $.trim(this.className);
    $(this).addClass("current");  
    $("#bigImage").removeClass().addClass("bigImage" + c); }
});
```

Comment: hello Nick, thanks for you answer. I checked both of your code, works correct in all browser also, but ie7 still not work. I made a live example http://jsbin.com/ehota4/3 to be able to edit it. Thanks!

Comment: @Sotiris - You can't have `smallImage` used repeatedly like that, it's an ID so it needs to be unique, give this a try: http://jsbin.com/ehota4/4

Comment: thank you!! very good, my eyes where always there and even didn't notice that I used an id three times! Big surprise! Thank you very much for this Nick!!!